# How do I fix the position of a button in typescript react

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux

I'm trying to position my button in TypeScript React. This is what I have so far:

```
<Button
    key="copy-to-clipboard"
    id="copy-to-clipboard"
    text="Copy"
    icon="file_copy"
    width={120}
    height={40}
    borderRadius={"3px"}
    onClick={copyToClipboard}
    margin="5px 10px"
/>
```

and the button is showing up at the Top Left of my page. I want the button to be positioned at the bottom center of the page, and immutable.

Edit:
I've tried the following, but my attempts have not been successful.

1. I imported the Container library

```
import { Container } from "@material-ui/core";
```

and have my code as such:

```
<Container fixed>
    <Button
         [same code as above]
     />
</Container>
```

my thought process is that I can have it in a container, and I can move the button around like that. I know this is an overly-complicated way of going about positioning the button, but all the code I've added in the button tag wasn't working.

2. I added float={center} below margin in the button code but that did not work.

Comment: button is a component that you have created or that comes from a library?

Comment: I have a button menu created, but I believe it's coming from a library

Comment: If that's a MaterialUI Button, it will not accept any CSS properties as props, nor `text` or `icon`. The [docs on styling](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/) would be a good place to start. If it is your button component and you are expecting those props, then show how they are being translated into CSS on the recieving end of the component. For what its worth, none of the pseudo-CSS you've included will do the job (`float: center` is also not valid CSS) - perhaps you should try and accomplish this with plain HTML/CSS first.

Comment: @lawrence-witt Thank you for the pointer. I realized that it was just a plain CSS issue, not react-js. Either way, I fixed the issue and I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this was just a plain CSS issue, this is what I did:

```
<div style={{position:"relative"}}>
    <div style={{position:"absolute", float: "right", bottom:-1170, right:0}}>
       <Button
          key="copy-to-clipboard"
          id="copy-to-clipboard"
          text="Copy"
          icon="file_copy"
          width={120}
          height={40}
          borderRadius={"3px"}
          onClick={copyToClipboard}
          margin="5px 10px"
        />
    </div>
</div>
```